# flash professional cs5 very slow responding

Tags: flash, adobe-cs5

I have a problem -- Flash CS5 is working very slow on Windows 7 x64, Intel Core Quad 2.5 GHZ, with newest NVidia driver. But on my by far less fast notebook everything working fine. Anyone spotted same problems? Could it be something with fonts?

Comment: Try turning off OpenGL acceleration features.  It isn't fonts.

Comment: Looks like I've found solution -- the problem was with Kasperski antivirus! 
http://community.acdsee.com/forums/topic/sluggishslow-problem-solved

Comment: When has Flash not been slow anyway? :)

Answer (score 0):

I removed two thirds of my fonts, now both flash and photoshop run fine.